# Multiple IF Statements not working from 3rd statement on

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm having issues getting the multiple If statement to work after the second statement.  I have 2500 rows of data questions sets that are tied to a 217 item drop down list.  What I'm trying to code is, that the questions applicable will populate based on the selected operation of the drop down list.  Questions applicable per operation vary from 3 - 12, and questions not applicable to the selection should automatically hide the rows. I've tried multiple variations of code, using ElseIf, If, combination If and ElseIf, combination If and Or_ (this is the most recent) as shown below.  Can someone please advise on this? I don't know what else to try and I need to add the additional 213 variables to the code.....Thanks

```
Sub Hide_Rows()

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TrigerCell As Range

Set Triggercell = Range("$J$14")
   
    If Not Application.Intersect(Triggercell, Target) Is Nothing Then
            If Triggercell.Value = "Electrician, farm based business" Then
                Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
                Rows("26:2500").Hidden = True
                Or_
            If Triggercell.Value = "Plumbing and heating contractors, farm based business" Then
                Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
                Rows("19:25", "47:2500").Hidden = True
                Or_
            If Triggercell.Value = "Plumbing contractors (plumber), farm based business" Then
                Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
                Rows("19:46", "55:2500").Hidden = True
                Or_
            If Triggercell.Value = "Assembly and installation of agricultural equipment in farm outbuildings, for others, farm based business" Then
                Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
                Rows("19:55", "61:2500").Hidden = True
            End If
    End If
End Sub

End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just missing `End If` statements after each `If` block?  What's the error in the code shown?

Comment: What is `Or_`?  That's not anything in the language that I'm familiar with.  You might want to consider using a `Select Case` for this, I think it would be the best fit for what you're doing.

Comment: Also: is this standalone VB, or is it VBA in Excel?  (My advice holds either way.)

Comment: David - I have no code error, the code just isn't working past the 2nd If statement

Comment: Craig - Or_ is used to continue the statement evaluation until the correct statement is reached.  The code works to the 2nd statement with or without the Or_.

Comment: Craig - this is VB code within an excel sheet

Comment: David - just modified the code to include End If after each statement but I have the same issue

Comment: "not compiling" and "not working" are two different things. "not working" implies the code did compile and is running. Your code is not compiling.

Comment: Craig - I just tried the code based on using Select Case but I'm getting an outcome the result can only be text and I'm trying to hide / unhide applicable questions sets to the statement.

Comment: Olivier - I can't find anything that addresses fixing code that is not compiling, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the result can only be text".  `Select Case` is a control flow construct, it doesn't have a *result*.  Maybe the issue is with one of the `Case`s, or maybe it's with the variable which you are selecting upon.

Comment: Read the compiler errors carefully. In `Dim TrigerCell As Range` the variable name has only one "g". Later you use a name with two "g"s. `Set` is not VB.NET. It's VB6 or VBA.  You have `If`s with missing `End If`s. There are two orphaned `End Sub`, etc. etc.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I've submitted an edit to update the tags, this is indeed VBA/Excel.  I think the orphaned `End Sub` statements might be partly from the edit by David.

Comment: `Rows("19:25", "47:2500").Hidden` should probably be `Rows("19:25, 47:2500").Hidden` where the ranges are in a single string.

Comment: Olivier - I've updated the trigger to reflect to gg's (that was an error thanks).  I've also amended the single strings to reflect as above but the results are the same.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Option Explicit On` as the first line in any module; that will make it so that misspelling a variable is an error, rather than silently creating something new.

Comment: Craig - thanks for the suggestion, I've added to my code and set as a default for new code but it didn't change the results which I assume means there are no other spelling errors

Comment: `End Sub` 3 times??

Comment: I don't think Set is used in vb.net code. This makes me think you are writing VBA code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Or_` is not something that exists in VBA, so it's not surprising that you're getting a compile error when you try to use it.  This usage is unusual enough that it's probably confusing the compiler, which may be why you don't get an error message until the second or third of them (or maybe even on an unrelated statement).

You can make this work with a `Select Case` statement or by using `ElseIf` between conditions.  I think `Select Case` is a little more natural for this problem.  It should look like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TriggerCell As Range

    Set Triggercell = Range("$J$14")

    If Application.Intersect(TriggerCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Select Case Triggercell.Value
        Case "Electrician, farm based business"
            Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
            Rows("26:2500").Hidden = True
        Case "Plumbing and heating contractors, farm based business"
            Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
            Rows("19:25").Hidden = True
            Rows("47:2500").Hidden = True
        'Etc.
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that (per comment on this answer) you can't specify two separate ranges to `Rows`, which was an issue with several of the blocks in the original code.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the code example.  I've updated to reflect but I'm getting the same results.  When it runs, it appears to be stopping at the 3 statement 1st line and showing all rows rather than just the one applicable to the statement                                      
Case "Plumbing contractors, farm based business"
            Rows("19:2500").Hidden = False
            Rows("19:46", "55:2500").Hidden = True

Comment: Sorry about the code example, I couldn't get it to paste properly

Comment: @Shelley Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?  Maybe if you do that, you'll see an obvious issue. I can't tell exactly what's going wrong right now.  If you're getting an error, please give the exact error message.

Comment: I have stepped through the code several time but there is no error message being displayed that way or using the "run" code button

Comment: @Shelley So if you don't have an error message, then there must be something else going wrong.  I'd suggest using some watch variables and watching the control flow to see how the actual execution differs from your mental model of how it should go.

Comment: I finally have this code fixed. I had to modify slightly from what you proposed by breaking apart the line that hid the row groups separated with a coma.  Essentially this Rows("19:46", "55:2500").Hidden = True became Rows("19:46").Hidden = True and Rows("55:2500").Hidden = True.  Slight modification and everything is working as intended.  Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: @Shelley Glad to hear you have it worked out.  I've updated my answer to take your additional issue into account.  If this is working for you, you may wish to mark the answer as accepted.